# Problem in finding Inverse Laplace

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

I have the following equation
[image]

But if I let $T_t(x,t)=constant$ then my equation becomes at **steady state**,
[image]

since partial differentiation of a constant=0, right?

here $\omega_bp_bc_b=M, $a constant and $T_a,Q(m),Q_r$ are also constants as well
Now I take the Laplace transform of the second equation,

and I come up with $L(T(x,s))={MT_a+Q(m)+Q_r \over sM}+{k\over M}{d^2 L(T(x,s))\over dx^2}$. Is this correct?

Now I want to take the inverse Laplace transform.  The boundary conditions and initial conditions are given by

$T_t(x,0)=T_c$

[image]

here $T_c$ is the body core temperature and since biologically the body core temperature tends to be stable $T_c$ is a constant.

How can I take the **inverse Laplace** of this?

I think it should be similar to
[image]

as is solved for a 2-D case in the [page 38, equation 43 in the article here](http://www.hrpub.org/download/201308/ujme.2013.010202.pdf)

---

I took the equation, letting $Q_r$ to be just similar to $Q_m$ for my purpose, 
$k{d^2T(x,t)\over dx^2}+M(T_a-T_t(x,t))+Q_m+Q_r$.  Then took the Laplace instead of taking it for `t` I took the transformation on `x` as you suggested.
Then I get,
$k(s^2L(T(s,t))-sT(0,t)-T'(0,t))+M {T_a\over S}-M L(T(s,t))+{Q_m+Q_r \over S}$.

If I let `t=0`, then I need to know the temperature at x=0 and assume that since at steady state this temperature doesn't change with time. Suppose I took it ass $T_t(0,0)=T_0$
then using boundary conditions I get,

$L(T(s,0))={ksT_0+h_0[T_s-T_0]-{MT_a \over s}-{(Q_m-Q_r)\over s}\over (ks^2 -M)}$ .

Is this correct. Can you check this please. And how am I going to get the inverse of this?
In the article [here](http://ijamm.bc.cityu.edu.hk/ijamm/outbox/Y2009V5N5P36C9209842.pdf)  they say through simple calculations they can obtain the solution [image]

I have no idea how they have got this. I think this solution is similar to my problem

Comment: Note that in your steady-state equation, you also need $Q_r(x,t)$ to be independent of $t$.  (You can differentiate the entire equation with respect to $t$ and both sides have to be zero.)  This completely removes $t$ from your equation.  Your notation $T(x,s)$ suggests that you are taking the Laplace transform $t \rightarrow s$, but $t$ isn't present any more...

Comment: @EricTowers what do you mean by `differentiate the entire equation with respect to t and both sides have to be zero.` Then what am I left with in the equation? So if `t` isn't present anymore can I take the Laplace transform?  I am not sure what steady state means. In the article here, http://ijamm.bc.cityu.edu.hk/ijamm/outbox/Y2009V5N5P36C9209842.pdf they take on t=0, initial temperature. Then can I take the Laplace and how do I go to inverse Laplace?

Comment: I mean $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ applied to $0$ gives $0$ and applied to $\kappa \dots Q_r(x,t)$ must give zero.  This means $\frac{\mathrm{d}Q_r(x,t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$.  Having elimnated all the $t$s, there's no way to take a transform from $t$ to anything else.  You could take a Laplace transform $x \rightarrow \xi$, and that might help you solve your equation.  But once you go down the road to steady state, time falls out completely.

Comment: @EricTowers I took  a Laplace transform $x→ξ$ as you suggested and edited it in my post. If you can go through it and tell me if it is correct it would be really helpful

Comment: At this point, I feel as if we're coming into the middle of a story and aren't quite sure why the characters are doing whatever they're doing.  What is the overarching problem you are trying to solve?  Are you finding solutions given an initial condition?  Are you trying to find consistent initial conditions?  I can't guess why you're taking transforms, so I can't guess if you're getting closer to your desired answer by doing so.  It would be good to know what the goal is so that we could tell whether you're getting closer to it.

Comment: @EricTowers I want to solve the equation $k{d^2T(x,t)\over dx^2}+M(T_a-T_t(x,t))+Q_m+Q_r$. This is to determine the temperature distribution in different layers of the skin. But to make the problem easier  for the time being I considered the all 3 layers as just one layer, that is in 1D form. And since if I consider how the temperature varies over time and location both, it would be a difficult task so I considered only the case where a person produces maximum energy when doing say exercises, so from that point onwards I considered the system to be steady state

Comment: By taking it as steady state I am trying to rule out the effect from time and only focus on temperature variation depending on location